# send multiple argument to query in GraphQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphql

i have this Query :

```
 Field<UserTypes>
            (
                "user",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IdGraphType>>
                { Name = "id" }),
                resolve: context =>
                {
                    var id = context.GetArgument<int>("id");
                    return userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());
                }
          );
```

but i need to pass multiple argument to this query . like username , name , lastname , . . .

how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the parameter for QueryArguments is a params, so you can simply add as many as you like, seperated by commas like so:

```
 Field<UserTypes>
        (
            "user",
            arguments: new QueryArguments
            (
               new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IdGraphType>> { Name = "id" },
               new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>> { Name = "username" },
               new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>> { Name = "name" },
               new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>> { Name = "lastname" }
            ),
            resolve: context =>
            {
                var id = context.GetArgument<int>("id");
                return userManager.FindByIdAsync(id.ToString());
            }
      );
```

Hope this helps you!